# Java 8 JAX-WS unmarshalling problems

Tags: java, java-8, jax-ws

I have a webservice working with Java8_77, however with Java8_131 it doesn't unmarshall the response properly.

The XML response is the next one. It returns data as in this example (I modified the information but the result is the same one):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope 
 xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
  <loginResponse xmlns="http://app.es">
    <loginReturn>
      <apellido1>surname1</apellido1>
      <apellido2>surname2</apellido2>
      <nif>id</nif>
      <nombre>name</nombre>
      <uid>uid</uid>
    </loginReturn>
  </loginResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I use jaxws-maven-plugin 2.4.1 to generate the code.

Here is the Service:

```
@WebService(name = "WSLoginLdap", targetNamespace = "http://app.es")
@XmlSeeAlso({ es.app.pojo.ObjectFactory.class, es.app.ws.ObjectFactory.class })
public interface WSLoginLdap {

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "loginReturn", targetNamespace = "http://app.es")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "login", targetNamespace = "http://app.es", className = "es.app.ws.Login")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "loginResponse", className = "es.app.ws.LoginResponse")
    public Respuesta login(@WebParam(name = "petic", targetNamespace = "http://app.es") PeticLogin petic);
}
```

ResponseWrapper:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "loginReturn"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "loginResponse")
public class LoginResponse {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Respuesta loginReturn;

    /**
     * setters / getters
     * /
}
```

Respuesta object:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Respuesta", propOrder = {
   "apellido1",
   "apellido2",
   "nif",
   "nombre",
   "uid"
})
public class Respuesta {

    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String apellido1;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String apellido2;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String nif;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String nombre;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String uid;

    /**
     * setters / getters
     * /
}
```

With Java8_77 my web service returns an object `Respuesta` with values in all its fields. With Java8_131 the object `Respuesta` has null in all its fields.

Ideas of what's going on?

**Edit: Found the issue!**

The WSDL of my webservice was generated with Axis (it's a very old WS). According to the WSDL, the object `Respuesta` belongs to the schema `http://pojo.app.es` so the plugin jaxws-maven-plugin generated the file `package-info.java` with the next code:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://pojo.app.es", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package pojo.app.ws;
```

As soon as I modified the schema to `http://app.es` it started working, with Java8_77 and Java8_131. I understand that this shouldn't have worked at all with previous versions of Java8, so it might be an error that Oracle fixed in newer versions.

Thanks.

Comment: Error stack please??

Comment: There is no errors. The issue is that my `Respuesta` object returned has `null` in all the fields, when it should have the data shown in the XML.

Comment: I'm sure that nothing would have broken due to updates. Can you double check?

Comment: Hey Keerthivasan, I just found the error. I edited my post with the explanation. Thanks!